# Microsoft Terminal Services (mstsc) protocol and port

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

Someone knows what is the protocol and which port Microsoft Terminal Services (mstsc) uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses TCP port 3389.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol